# Making quoted text pretty using javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to make lines of text prefixed with `>` to be wrapped in `<span class="quoted"></span>`.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    x = $('DIV#test').html();
    x = x.replace(/(^|\n)&gt;([^\n]+)(\n|$)/g, "$1<span class=\"quoted\">$2</span>$3");
    $('DIV#test').html(x);
});
```

I can't find a reason why, but this makes only odd lines quoted in Chrome and in IE it makes all text gray. Any ideas what is wrong with this code?

Demo at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jBJ6V/1/

Comment: Though I don't have a solution .. I can point out your problem.. It seems the regular expression is working this way..
Firstline it scans from "\n>" till "\n"
then next line it again looks for "\n>"
But '\n' was already consumed in the previous scanning..
Hope this helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `m` ("multiline") flag on the regular expression rather than the alternation at the outset (and with the necessary adjustments to the resulting capture groups):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    x = $('DIV#test').html();
    x = x.replace(/^&gt;([^\n]+)$/gm, "<span class=\"quoted\">$1</span>");
    // Changes:    ^----here----^      ^--here                ^^--here-^
    $('DIV#test').html(x);
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jBJ6V/6/)

The `m` flag tells the regular expression to treat `^` and `$` as relative to individual lines, not relative to the string as a whole. More in sections [15.10.2.6](http://es5.github.com/#x15.10.2.6) and [15.10.2.7](http://es5.github.com/#x15.10.2.7) of the specification, and [on MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: Thank you for explaining where I was wrong. This works fine in all browsers except IE. In IE all the content of <div> keeps wrapperd in one span - linebreaks are just ignored (it works in jsFiddle demo, but when I get text from mySQL DB - it's the same all the time). Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @SilverLight, IE7 and IE8 give different result for the .html() as explained here http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2004/11/innerhtml_and_t.html

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work in IE is that older IE handles innerHTML differently, and this reflects in jQuery having different results of .html().

Try this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jBJ6V/8/

I ran it through 7,8 and 9 compatibility modes and seems to be working.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Yeah sorry, I figured he would see the m flag and go asking himself what is that and google for information to self-learn :)